# AFNetWorking Download Session does not update my file

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, afnetworking-2

still new to objective C i have discover the amazing AFNetworking network class.

Using the dic i have my code which download my file and write into the NSDocumentDirectory

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myAdress/Menu.plist"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response)
{
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
    return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

    NSDictionary *dicMenuPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[filePath path]];
    NSLog(@"Dic Menu Plist = %@",dicMenuPlist);


}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

this works fine but when i change something in my Menu.plist file the changes does not appear, i have to delete my app then download the file that has changed.

I do not understand why i have to do this.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: just delete local file before download

Comment: no but i want the file to be uploaded without deleting the app, the user will have to delete the app to get the last data ?? ?

Comment: no, a mean delete the local copy of `Menu.plist` not the app itself

Comment: a Yea, i have understand, you mean i delete the file then i download ... It does not explain me why AFNetworking act likes this but thanks.

Comment: Its probably caching the file and doesnt know that its been updated. It assumes you already have the file so it doesn't download it again. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#does-afnetworking-have-any-caching-mechanisms-built-in

Answer (score 1):

The answer given [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1687).

Delete the existing file in the destination block.

```
destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

   NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
   NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];

   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
   if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
      // delete existing file (using file URL above)
   }
   return fileURL;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default method AFNetworking 3.0 don't refresh that you downloader files.

If you want rewrite this file in Objective-C +iOS9.0, you need do that:

```
- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *) downloadDocsFromUrl:(NSString *) url withSuccesBlock:(DocModelBlock) docModelBlock withErrorBlock:(ErrorBlock) errorBlock {

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.sessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:&error];

        if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSURL *urlPath = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];

            if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:urlPath.path]) {
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:urlPath.path error:&error];
            }
        }

        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            errorBlock(error);
        } else {
            docModelBlock(filePath);
        }
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];

    return downloadTask;
}
```